# 20-pin 20 mm connector identification

Tags: connector, identification

Can anyone help me to identify that pin connector? It's exactly 20 mm and got 20 pins. (It's used from Battery Management System to battery cells.) Thanks.

[image: Photo 1 of connector]

[image: Photo 2 of connector]

Comment: One of these common JST connectors. You can consult one of many online catalogs by first searching this term.

Comment: Which distance is exactly 20 mm?

Comment: @Huisman, probably the top picture is 20 mm .... 20 pins with 1 mm spacing ... that makes 19 mm plus 1/2 mm on each end

Comment: @jsotola But if these squares on the paper are 5mm x 5mm, the width is visibly less than *exactly 20 mm*!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the 20 way SH series connector from JST: [SHR-20V-S-B](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=231)

But the widths do not correspond to OP's *exactly 20 mm*.

Comment: the questions is what is being measured at 20mm. I agree the housing matches exactly groves and all. Connector without protrusions comes in at 19mm and with protrusions(tabs) it is 23. I say you are Melted plastic could carry a 1mm difference.